# [Excel]Compare a value to multiple ranges and return what range the value came from as a category(categories are ranked)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have been using Excel (2010) at lot more for work and I've been trying to <strike>excel</strike> get better at using this tool.

What I want to do in the end is compare the value of a cell to multiple ranges of values (each range is its own category). If the initial value matches a value in one of the ranges/category, then the end result would be to display what category it came from. Some categories are ranked higher than others, so the higher ranked category takes precedent over lower ranked ones

Since this seems a little complicated for me to tackle (I am a novice), I decided to start from a simpler, example problem and work my way up:

I have 10 cells with values 1 - 10. I have two categories, one for odd numbers, and one for even numbers. I got my formula to work with:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$14:$A$18,A2),CELL("contents",$F$2),IF(COUNTIF($A$21:$A$25,A2),CELL("contents",$F$3),"ERROR"))

where A2 = cell which I am comparing to the other ranges
      $A$14:$A$18 = my range of odd numbers
      $F$2 = "ODD"
      $A$21:$A$25 = my range of even numbers
      $F$3 = "EVEN"
```

Now, I wanted to add a 3rd category that has a higher rank than the two I have, a "PRIME" number category. Seeing how 2 is both from the "EVEN" category and the "PRIME" category, I would like the "PRIME" number category to be displayed and override any other category.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You could use `Application.Match` in an `If ... Then ... ElseIf ... Then ...` also doing that in a `For Each` may help...

Answer (score 0):

Just by phone (may contain errors) for VBA:

```
Public Function getRangeName(str As String) As String
  Dim MyRanges as Variant, MyNames As Variant, i As Long
  MyRanges = Array(Range("A1:A10"), Range("B1:B10"), Range("C1:C10"))
  MyNames = Array("Range A", "Range B", "Range C")
  For i = 0 To 2
    If IsNumeric (Application.Match(str, MyRanges(i), 0)) Then
      getRangeName = MyNames(i)
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

It will stop at the first range it finds and output it and nothing `""` if it was nowhere

Also if the ranges stick together you could use something like that:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MAX((A1:C8="Search String")*COLUMN((A1:C1))),"range a","range b","range c"),"")
```

As an array formula (formula needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) it will output the highest range (c > b > a)

Doing it for non-contiguous ranges which are at least at the same height (going for A1:A10, C1:C10 and E1:E10 only)

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(MAX((A1:E10="Search String")*{2,0,3,0,1}),"range e","range a","range c"),"")
```

also the order is different (c > a > e)... also needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER